# Extremely large loss and wrong transcript after training

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

I am currently implementing DeepSpeech for my language. I have 2 directories: train and test. Train has approximately 15000 wavs and test approximately 3000. The problem that I face is during training I have large losses, and for the test part loss is huge.[image]

Unfortunately the words are not recognized as it should be. This is my sh file
[image]

Could you please give me some hints on what I should do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The new [DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook) has sections on both [training](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/TRAINING.html) and [testing](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/TESTING.html) that can provide some guidance here.

One thing that stands out immediately is that you have no *validation set*. This would be the first thing I would change - ensuring that you have a *validation set*. See [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7) for more information on the difference between test, validation and training sets.

You are using a custom `alphabet.txt` file which is great - I'm assuming that this contains all the characters of the Romanian alphabet?

The next thing here would be to *reducing learning rate on plateau* - this is covered in the PlayBook.

Mult noroc.